# emission with volume question

Tags: emission

ok so I was trying to make an **explosion without baking** using the **empty** and modifiers method, I modelled something that kind of looks like an explosion then I added displacement with mods etc now when I tried adding emission these cubes appeared, I can't really find a fix so can anyone here help me?[image: this is what happens when I try adding emmission]

Comment: could you let us know what specific modifiers you have going? or preferably include the blender file? I suspect you have some modifier thats adding extra geometry. If you are using volumetrics and the mesh looks similar to the cube shape, you have to make sure that you have the emission connected to some kind of volumetric input

Comment: yes sure i used a mesh to volume modifier and a volume displacement mod
@ChrisHowe

Comment: also the mesh looks like an explosion but without those cloudy displacement, just looks so smooth
and I used a principled volume node and an add shader node, with the second socket being an emission node @ChrisHowe